# Question about characterisation of smoothness of a morphism of schemes in Olsson's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, schemes

I am confused about a characterisation Olsson gives for smoothness of a morphism of schemes in his book Algebraic Spaces and Stacks. This is the Theorem, on page 15 of the book,[image]

In particular, I am confused about the phrase "for every commutative diagram of schemes". If I am understanding the proof correctly, and understanding smoothness, this result requires that $Y'$ be affine. Is this just an omission? I can't see how this can be equivalent to the definition given for smoothness otherwise.

As an aside question, when authors use the term "let $Y$ be an affine $S$-scheme", do they mean that $Y$ is an $S$-scheme and $Y$ is affine, or do they mean that $Y$ is relatively affine to $S$?

Comment: No need for Y’ to be affine. This result is just saying “smooth=formally smooth + locally of finite presentation.” See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02H6 for example. Also for your second question they mean Y is an S-scheme and Y is affine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I had initially thought, but I thought that formally smooth also requires an affine hypothesis there. For example https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02H0. They claim in the next paragraph that it can be dropped for etale or unramified, but not smooth.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I glossed over “affine,” the most important word! Can you add Olsson’s definition of smooth in the question so maybe we can see if there’s a mathematical reason these two sources differ?

Comment: I understand the confusion now. Olsson’s definition says “you can fill in the dotted arrow” in the definition of formally smooth morphism of schemes Zariski locally on $Y’$. The stacks project also says this (later in the paragraph you pointed out).

Comment: For your aside question: page 24 refers to "affine $S$-schemes," but unfortunately $S$ is affine, so it doesn't really clarify. (Although if $S$ were not affine, it would indicate that what is meant is "an $S$-scheme which is an affine scheme" as opposed to "an $S$-scheme with affine structure morphism.) Formally smooth does typically require an affine hypothesis on the scheme itself, as opposed to the structure morphism (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GZ)), and so given definition 1.3.1 I would assume that "affine $S$-scheme" means "an $S$-scheme which is an affine scheme."

Comment: @SamirCanning In your final comment, are you agreeing that one needs $Y'$ needs to be affine, or saying that it doesn't need to be?

Comment: @AlexClark $Y’$ does not need to be affine. The requirement in Olsson’s definition is that there is a Zariski covering of $Y’$ such that on each element of the cover, one can fill in the dotted arrow in the definition of formally smooth. The catch is that the morphisms that fill in the dotted arrow Zariski locally don’t have to glue together to give a map $Y’\rightarrow X$.

Comment: @SamirCanning I've been thinking about this a bit more in the meantime. That last comment actually clears everything up perfectly, so thank you! It's really quite a subtle distinction I guess. Is there any situation where you would care about there being a collection of morphisms on some collection of affine subsets without them gluing?